# Java Spring Framework Error

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I am novice to java development, all of my java profile team member has tried to sort it out, but no one have idea of the exact problem.

I am getting this error on browser after starting tomcat details given below.

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: org.apache.tiles.util.TilesIOException: JSPException including path '/views/layout/leftNavigation.jsp'.


    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:549)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:455)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        com.snapdeal.web.filter.CustomWhiteSpaceFilter.doFilter(CustomWhiteSpaceFilter.java:80)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1180)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        com.snapdeal.web.filter.CustomWhiteSpaceFilter.doFilter(CustomWhiteSpaceFilter.java:80)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1180)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        org.springframework.web.filter.ShallowEtagHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ShallowEtagHeaderFilter.java:58)
        org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
        org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)
        org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
        org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
        org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:381)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:368)
        org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
        org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
        org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
        org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:100)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
        org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
        org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:112)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
        org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
        org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
        org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:177)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
        org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
        org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
        org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
        org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:169)
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
        com.snapdeal.web.filter.RequestIdentifierFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestIdentifierFilter.java:192)
        org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
        org.owasp.esapi.filters.ClickjackFilter.doFilter(ClickjackFilter.java:98)
        com.snapdeal.web.filter.CustomWhiteSpaceFilter.doFilter(CustomWhiteSpaceFilter.java:80)
    root cause

    javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: org.apache.tiles.util.TilesIOException: JSPException including path '/views/layout/leftNavigation.jsp'.
        org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:908)
        org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:841)
        org.apache.jsp.views.deal.homePage_jsp._jspService(homePage_jsp.java:121)
        org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        com.snapdeal.web.filter.CustomWhiteSpaceFilter.doFilter(CustomWhiteSpaceFilter.java:80)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1180)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        com.snapdeal.web.filter.CustomWhiteSpaceFilter.doFilter(CustomWhiteSpaceFilter.java:80)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1180)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        org.springframework.web.filter.ShallowEtagHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ShallowEtagHeaderFilter.java:58)
        org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
        org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)
        org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
        org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
        org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:381)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:368)
        org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
        org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
        org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
        org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:100)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
        org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
        org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:112)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
        org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
        org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
        org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:177)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
        org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
        org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
        org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
        org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:169)
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
        com.snapdeal.web.filter.RequestIdentifierFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestIdentifierFilter.java:192)
        org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
        org.owasp.esapi.filters.ClickjackFilter.doFilter(ClickjackFilter.java:98)
        com.snapdeal.web.filter.CustomWhiteSpaceFilter.doFilter(CustomWhiteSpaceFilter.java:80)
    root cause

    javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: org.apache.tiles.util.TilesIOException: JSPException including path '/views/layout/leftNavigation.jsp'.
        org.apache.jsp.views.deal.homePage_jsp$Helper.invoke(homePage_jsp.java:1453)
        org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspUtil.evaluateFragmentAsString(JspUtil.java:297)
        org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.PutAttributeTag.doTag(PutAttributeTag.java:256)
        org.apache.jsp.views.deal.homePage_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005fputAttribute_005f3(homePage_jsp.java:210)
        org.apache.jsp.views.deal.homePage_jsp.access$3(homePage_jsp.java:198)
        org.apache.jsp.views.deal.homePage_jsp$Helper.invoke0(homePage_jsp.java:1307)
        org.apache.jsp.views.deal.homePage_jsp$Helper.invoke(homePage_jsp.java:1433)
        org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspUtil.evaluateFragment(JspUtil.java:279)
        org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertTemplateTag.doTag(InsertTemplateTag.java:254)
        org.apache.jsp.views.deal.homePage_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsertTemplate_005f0(homePage_jsp.java:140)
        org.apache.jsp.views.deal.homePage_jsp._jspService(homePage_jsp.java:114)
        org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        com.snapdeal.web.filter.CustomWhiteSpaceFilter.doFilter(CustomWhiteSpaceFilter.java:80)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1180)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        com.snapdeal.web.filter.CustomWhiteSpaceFilter.doFilter(CustomWhiteSpaceFilter.java:80)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1180)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        org.springframework.web.filter.ShallowEtagHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ShallowEtagHeaderFilter.java:58)
        org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
        org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)
        org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
        org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
        org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:381)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:368)
        org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
        org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
        org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
        org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:100)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
        org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
        org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:112)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
        org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
        org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
        org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:177)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
        org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
        org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
        org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
        org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:169)
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
        com.snapdeal.web.filter.RequestIdentifierFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestIdentifierFilter.java:192)
        org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
        org.owasp.esapi.filters.ClickjackFilter.doFilter(ClickjackFilter.java:98)
        com.snapdeal.web.filter.CustomWhiteSpaceFilter.doFilter(CustomWhiteSpaceFilter.java:80)
    root cause

    org.apache.tiles.util.TilesIOException: JSPException including path '/views/layout/leftNavigation.jsp'.
        org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletUtil.wrapServletException(ServletUtil.java:241)
        org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesRequestContext.java:105)
        org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.dispatch(JspTilesRequestContext.java:96)
        org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.TemplateAttributeRenderer.write(TemplateAttributeRenderer.java:44)
        org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
        org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.ChainedDelegateAttributeRenderer.write(ChainedDelegateAttributeRenderer.java:76)
        org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
        org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:670)
        org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:336)
        org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.renderAttribute(InsertAttributeModel.java:210)
        org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.end(InsertAttributeModel.java:126)
        org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.doTag(InsertAttributeTag.java:311)
        org.apache.jsp.views.deal.homePage_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsertAttribute_005f0(homePage_jsp.java:228)
        org.apache.jsp.views.deal.homePage_jsp.access$8(homePage_jsp.java:215)
        org.apache.jsp.views.deal.homePage_jsp$Helper.invoke2(homePage_jsp.java:1340)
        org.apache.jsp.views.deal.homePage_jsp$Helper.invoke(homePage_jsp.java:1439)
        org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspUtil.evaluateFragmentAsString(JspUtil.java:297)
        org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.PutAttributeTag.doTag(PutAttributeTag.java:256)
        org.apache.jsp.views.deal.homePage_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005fputAttribute_005f3(homePage_jsp.java:210)
        org.apache.jsp.views.deal.homePage_jsp.access$3(homePage_jsp.java:198)
        org.apache.jsp.views.deal.homePage_jsp$Helper.invoke0(homePage_jsp.java:1307)
        org.apache.jsp.views.deal.homePage_jsp$Helper.invoke(homePage_jsp.java:1433)
        org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspUtil.evaluateFragment(JspUtil.java:279)
        org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertTemplateTag.doTag(InsertTemplateTag.java:254)
        org.apache.jsp.views.deal.homePage_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsertTemplate_005f0(homePage_jsp.java:140)
        org.apache.jsp.views.deal.homePage_jsp._jspService(homePage_jsp.java:114)
        org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        com.snapdeal.web.filter.CustomWhiteSpaceFilter.doFilter(CustomWhiteSpaceFilter.java:80)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1180)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        com.snapdeal.web.filter.CustomWhiteSpaceFilter.doFilter(CustomWhiteSpaceFilter.java:80)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1180)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        org.springframework.web.filter.ShallowEtagHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ShallowEtagHeaderFilter.java:58)
        org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
        org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)
        org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
        org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
        org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:381)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:368)
        org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
        org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
        org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
        org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:100)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
        org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
        org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:112)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
        org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
```

Please help me

Comment: Can you show us your `TilesViewResolver` configuration? Your jsp code?  Is the file really in the path that you excpect?

Comment: post more details like posting your code,after what you did then you got this error etc,if your details are more then you will get answers more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tiles definition might be a problem.

From the exception JSPException including path '/views/layout/leftNavigation.jsp'.

Instead of "/views/layout/leftNavigation.jsp" please use "views/layout/leftNavigation.jsp"

Answer (score 0):

Given the fact that there are elements in the stacktrace that are being repeated over and over again, it may be a circular dependency between the resources you're trying to include

For example :

Your /views/layout/leftNavigation.jsp can include(direct or via some other page) a page xyz.jsp , which in turn tries to include leftNavigation.jsp.